# How do i solve this error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ..\modules\highgui\src\ error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying this code but its giving error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2)
while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    image = cv2.imread('D:\dataset\signProject\amer_sign2.png')
    cv2.imshow("image", image)
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    top, right, bottom, left = 75, 350, 300, 590
    roi = img[top:bottom, right:left]
    roi=cv2.flip(roi,1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    cv2.imshow('roi',gray)
    alpha=classify(gray)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0,255,0), 2)
    font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(img,alpha,(0,130),font,5,(0,0,255),2)
    #cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key==ord('q'):
        break;
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

ERROR

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [45], in <cell line: 4>()
      4 ret, img = cap.read()
      5 image = cv2.imread('D:\dataset\signProject\amer_sign2.png')
----> 6 cv2.imshow("image", image)
      7 img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
      8 top, right, bottom, left = 75, 350, 300, 590

error: OpenCV(4.5.1) ..\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhLJu.png)

Comment: May can I see function of classify? alpha=classify(gray). It worked for me. But I seeing no error.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should always use such `if` blocks checking if the image is read correctly.

```
if img and img.size != 0:
     // do the work
```

Your image is not read properly from the error message you showed. Check if the image exists and it is in correct format etc.

You can also use this function `cv2.haveImageReader` which checks whether the specified image can be decoded by OpenCV. It returns `True` or `False`.

```
val = cv2.haveImageReader(filename)
```